# Morphia with MongoDB connection

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, morphia, nosql

I have running MongoDB server, created test1 database with collection called zips. (taken from http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json). Now I want to read it from my application using Morphia.

following morphia tutorial(https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/GettingStarted):
I created maven project, and upadated dependencies(https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Dependencies). now my project contain only entity class and main.
Entity class:

```
package com.mycompany.morphia;

import com.sun.corba.se.spi.ior.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotationsEntity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
     @Id String _id; //maybe ObjectId ?
  String city;
  Object loc;
  Integer pop;
  String state;

}
```

and main class

```
package com.mycompany.morphia;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        MongoClient m = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        Datastore ds = new Morphia().createDatastore(m, "test1");
        MyEntity e = ds.find(MyEntity.class).get();
        System.out.println( e.city.toString());
        System.in.read();
    }
 }
```

Still while debugging I got null. I don't know how to check if I'm connected to my db, and how to properly query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my @Entity

```
public Object loc;
```

Object type caused the problem. I simply removed it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use ObjectId instead of String
2. `com.sun.corba.se.spi.ior.ObjectId` is the wrong package — use `org.bson.types.ObjectId` instead
3. What does `e.toString()` give you?

Comment: 1. I have changed to ObjectId, no changes.
2. I see no differences in packages you wrote. 
3. MyEntity e = ds.find(MyEntity.class).get(); is null

Any more ideas?

Comment: I think you mean she should use `org.bson.types.ObjectId` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a null, then you're connected to the database.  Your output suggests that the first document in that collection doesn't contain a field called "city."

Comment: evanchooly -->Changing to org.bson.types.ObjectId does not changed anything.
I'm no sure if I'm conneced because if I change "test1" anything else (eg. "asdfsdfdsf") I receive the same result. 
You suggest that first file does not contain 'city' but it does not contain anything. Moreover I'm sure that 'zips' collection contains given i firts post records - I've checked ti in MongoDB shell.
I wonder if I have MyEntitity coded properly...

Comment: If it changes something in MongoDB shell i use db.zips.find() to see my records od DB.
while running my project i got error:
    Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project morphia: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Annotate your entity with @Entity("zips").  By default morphia uses the classname for the collection name but your data is in the zips collection.

Comment: I already tried it - my entity loks like that:
    @Entity("zips")
public class MyEntity {
    public @Id ObjectId _id;
  public String city;
  public Object loc;
  public Integer pop;
  public String state;
  
}

Comment: What you've shown here is not annotated like that.  In the shell, run this:  `db.zips.findOne()` and post the resulting document.

Comment: maybe I need to specify password and username somewhere?
I can post whole project if it would help...

Comment: After run db.zips.findOne() I got first record, namley:
{ "_id" : "35004",
"city" : "ACMAR",
"loc" : [
-86.51557,
33.584132
],
"pop" : 6055,
"state" : "AL"
}

Comment: two thoughts:

1.  That's from the `test1` database, yes?
2.  You're *sure* your entity has `@Entity("zips")` at the class declaration?

Comment: yest, it was performed on db test1, my entity class lokks like:
package com.mycompany.morphia;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

@Entity("zips")
public class MyEntity {
    public @Id ObjectId _id;
  public String city;
  public Object loc;
  public Integer pop;
  public String state;
  
}

Comment: I think I know what cause he problem. My field _id is defined as "_id":"35004" . so basically it is a string. But '@Id' require ObjectId. Now is the question: how to define '@Id' by type of ObjectId but is readed from string?

Comment: @Id does not require ObjectId.  Your ID field can be whatever you'd like (including a complex object/document).  So in this case, you can change your _id Java field to a String and be fine.

Comment: ok, so back to String... aaand i got problem in console: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [className]